# How do I edit multiple text fields with a unified state/handler?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Background:**

I am successfully able to use separate states/handlers to populate and edit my text fields, but I would like to simplify/condense my code by creating a unified state and a unified handler for many of my text fields.

**Problem:**

I am successfully able to obtain the correct values with `useEffect`, but when I try to edit one of the text fields I get an error message saying: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`

**My Code:**

```
useEffect(() => {
  getDataFromApi(props.id).then((rsp) => {
    setData(rsp);
    textFields.firstItem = rsp.content?.firstItem;
    textFields.secondItem = rsp.content?.secondItem;
  });
}, []);

const [textFields, setTextFields] = useState({
  firstItem: "",
  secondItem: "",
});

const handleChangeTextField = (type) => (e) => {
  setTextFields((prevState) => ({
    ...prevState,
    [type]: e.target.value,
  }));
};

<TextField
  id="firstItem"
  value={textFields.firstItem}
  onChange={handleChangeTextField("firstItem")}
/>
<TextField
  id="secondItem"
  value={textFields.secondItem}
  onChange={handleChangeTextField("secondItem")}
/>
```

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong would be helpful!

Thanks.

Comment: do you use material-ui core textfiled? but I can't get an error like that. Please confirm here https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-bxn8k?file=/demo.js

Comment: No, I am not using material-ui. I am using `https://polaris.shopify.com/components/forms/text-field`

Comment: Try using the setTextFields hook instead after calling getDataFromApi(). It should look something like this...

getDataFromApi(props.id).then((rsp) => {
    setData(rsp);
    setTextFields({
        firstItem: value,
        secondItem: value
    })
  });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use that try like this.

```
  const [textFields, setTextFields] = useState({
    firstItem: "",
    secondItem: ""
  });

  const handleChangeTextField = (type) => (value) => {
    setTextFields((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [type]: value
    }));
  };

        <TextField
          id="firstItem"
          variant="filled"
          value={textFields.firstItem}
          onChange={handleChangeTextField("firstItem")}
        />
     
        <TextField
          id="secondItem"
          value={textFields.secondItem}
          variant="filled"
          onChange={handleChangeTextField("secondItem")}
        />
```

You can confirm here. https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-davinci-3x0ui?file=/App.js:0-865